# How to use mouseover and mouseout in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have this older Angular code which works but not in the latest version of Angular 6.

```
<div ng-mouseover="changeText=true" ng-mouseleave="changeText=false" ng-init="changeText=false">
  <span ng-hide="changeText">Hide</span>
  <span ng-show="changeText">Show</span>
</div>
```

How do i make this work for Angular 6? I understand I have to use `(mouseover)` and `(mouseout)` but I couldn't implement it successfully.

Comment: AngularJS was completely re-written to become Angular2+, where have you been:). In other words AngularJS syntax will never work with Angular6.

Comment: Cast away in some isolated island and couldn't get out.

Comment: Welcome back:) there is a lot to catch up on. I would recommend completely forgetting about AngularJS, and start with Angular6 - might as well start from scratch.

Comment: I'm doing that and couldn't find an article that explains (mouseout) successfully and hence asked here.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The Angular6 equivalent code should be:

**app.component.html**

```
<div (mouseover)="changeText=true" (mouseout)="changeText=false">
  <span *ngIf="!changeText">Hide</span>
  <span *ngIf="changeText">Show</span>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-main',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    changeText: boolean;
    constructor() {
       this.changeText = false;
    }
}
```

Notice that there is no such thing as `$scope` anymore as it existed in AngularJS. Its been replaced with member variables from the component class. Also, there is no scope resolution algorithm based on prototypical inheritance either - it either resolves to a component class member, or it doesn't.

Comment: dont forget, in your `.ts` file you should add a variable named `changeText: boolean = false`

Comment: how does that matter, even if you don't have `changeText` defined in `ts` its not gonna break.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying `[hidden]` instead of using `!`. This solves it :)

Comment: @Stavm I added `public changeText;` on top of the constructor. I hope that's the same?

Comment: @NikitaGupta it is the same. I assume you added `public` because TSLINT was yelling at you. @manish on the same line of thoughts, you can build a whole HTML page using only `<div>` elements, and style them with CSS. you can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: @Stavm Thank you. btw, the DIV is in a `*ngFor` repeat and the is repeated x times. When I mouseover, it changes in all the DIVs. I want the mouseover effect to change only where it is hovered over, not on all the divs. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Nice solution but how the same can be achieved for multiple labels? I have 30 anchors and want to change the text which was hovered.

Answer (score 23):

Adding to what was already said.

if you want to `*ngFor` an element , and hide \ show elements in it, on hover, like you added in the comments, you should re-think the whole concept.

a more appropriate way to do it, does not involve angular at all.
I would go with pure CSS instead, using its native `:hover` property.

something like:

**App.Component.css**

```
div span.only-show-on-hover {
    visibility: hidden;
}
div:hover span.only-show-on-hover  {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**App.Component.html**

```
  <div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4]" > hover me please.
    <span class="only-show-on-hover">you only see me when hovering</span>
  </div>
```

Demo: [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-hvgx7n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: This is surely much more efficient than using *ngIf in a loop

Answer (score 17):

```
To avoid blinking problem use following code
its not mouseover and mouseout instead of that use mouseenter and mouseleave


**app.component.html**

    <div (mouseenter)="changeText=true" (mouseleave)="changeText=false">
      <span *ngIf="!changeText">Hide</span>
      <span *ngIf="changeText">Show</span>
    </div>

**app.component.ts**

@Component({
   selector: 'app-main',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    changeText: boolean;
    constructor() {
       this.changeText = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be "mouseleave" and not "mouseLeave"

Comment: mouseleave is better then mouseout if you need to detect when the mouse is getting out of the element scope

Answer (score 3):

If your interested , then go with directive property . Code might looks bit tough , but itshows all the property of Angular 6 . Here am adding a sample code

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer2 ,HostListener,HostBinding,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { MockNgModuleResolver } from '@angular/compiler/testing';
//import { Event } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBetterHighlight]'
})
export class BetterHighlightDirective implements OnInit {
   defaultcolor :string = 'black'
   Highlightedcolor : string = 'red'
    @HostBinding('style.color') color : string = this.defaultcolor;

  constructor(private elm : ElementRef , private render:Renderer2) { }
ngOnInit()
{}
@HostListener('mouseenter') mouseover(event :Event)
{

  this.color= this.Highlightedcolor ;
}
@HostListener('mouseleave') mouseleave(event: Event)
{

  this.color = this.defaultcolor;
}
}
```

Just use the selector name 'appBetterHighlight' anywhere in the template to access this  property .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(mouseover)` and `(mouseout)` events.

> component.ts

```
changeText:boolean=true;
```

> component.html

```
<div (mouseover)="changeText=true" (mouseout)="changeText=false">
  <span [hidden]="changeText">Hide</span>
  <span [hidden]="!changeText">Show</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have marked the first answer as solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div (mouseenter)="changeText=true" (mouseout)="changeText=false">
  <span *ngIf="!changeText">Hide</span>
  <span *ngIf="changeText">Show</span>
</div>
```

and if you want to use in *ngFor then assign the object value of hover data and then check its id and show hover info/icon or anything like that:-

```
 <div (mouseenter)="hoverCard(d)" (mouseleave)="hoverCard(null)" *ngFor="let d of data" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-4">
   <a *ngIf="hoverData && hoverData.id == d.id" class="text-right"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Hover Text</a>
    Normal Text
  </div>
```

in TS File

```
  hoverData!:Data|null;

  hoverCard(d: Data|null){
    this.hoverData = d;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`CSS` solution works without a glitch!

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJ4PCJMVQ4LN
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJ4PPLCCEBRG

```css
.col-info:hover>.popoverIcon {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.popoverIcon {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4]">

  <div class="col-info">
    <span class=" popoverIcon ">Show {{i}}</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML:

```
<div (mouseover)="funcName1() (mouseout)="funcName2()">
   // Do what you want 
</div>
```

In TypeScript:

```
funcName1(){
 //Do Something
}
funcName2(){
//Do Something
}
```