# hover an item to show div specific to it

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using `*ngFor` to loop & show items in `deals` array

```
   <div class="card item" *ngFor="let deal of deals; let i = index">
      <div class="card-body item-body">...</div>
    </div>
```

what i want to achieve, is when i am hovering div `card` in the html, his corresponding `card-body` div will be shown.
its a fairly easy task using jquery, but i am failing to do it, using Angular.

i search for a solution for that, but didn't succeeded to implement it..
What is the way to achieve that?

Comment: please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491225/how-to-use-mouseover-and-mouseout-in-angular-6

Comment: @NoHoney_k1ll, isn't this will show/hide all items div's with the class `card-body`?

Comment: you can add another validation like *ngIf=currentCard == i
And i is your index

Comment: this solution is not working for me.. isn't there a simple solution to just toggle the hovered div on hover?

Comment: @E.Meir. Where is the corresponding body shown? Beside the card-body?  Like a Tip?

Comment: @harold_mean2 its showing inside the "card" [link](http://prntscr.com/l0lenp)

Comment: @E.Meir. I assume your deal object is an interface and you should be able to get its description by deal.description and other objects. In my e-comerce app, I use (mouseover)="onMouseoverDetail()" to show more about this product and (mouseleave)="onMouseleave()" to store its original state. Hope this help.

Comment: harold_mean2 yes. my deal object is an interface, but how can i show more details on hover? something like `javascript toggle` for this item in array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
  <div class="card item" *ngFor="let deal of deals; let i = index">
      <div  (mouseenter) ="onHover(i)"  (mouseleave) ="onHover(-1)>
       <div *ngIf = "i == hoverIndex" class="card-body item-body">...</div>
      </div >
    </div>
```

in your .ts file

```
hoverIndex:number = -1;
```

and the method

```
onHover(i:number){
 this.hoverIndex = i;
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error `<ng-template [ERROR ->] Event binding mouseenter not emitted by any directive on an embedded template.`

Comment: can you please use div tag istead of ng-template and test?

Comment: I have used that in angular 4.  if this don't work this should work. instead ng-template < div (mouseover)="onHover(i)" (mouseout) = "onHover(-1)">

Comment: can you please tell , what is the working solution div tag instead ng-template or second method? i want to edit the answer.