# how to change color of text on mouse enter using angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4.1.x

i am a newbie to programming. I have tried this code but @hostlistner part is not working
 i have used bootstrap version 4

it doesn't give any compile error also

```
 element.nativeElement.style.color = 'red'
```

this statement is working but

```
 this.element.nativeElement.style.color = 'blue';
```

this one doesn't

```
      import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

         @Directive({
          selector: '[setmycolor]'
           })
          export class SetmycolorDirective {

          constructor(private element:ElementRef) {
          element.nativeElement.style.color = 'red';
          }


          @HostListener('onmouseenter')onMouseEnter(){
          this.element.nativeElement.style.color = 'blue';
          }

          }
```

the code in app

Comment: The name of the event is `mouseenter`, not `onmouseenter`.

Comment: addind an event listener in javascript is object.addEventListener("mouseenter", myScript). Then as @JBNizet said , is mouseenter

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491225/how-to-use-mouseover-and-mouseout-in-angular-6

Comment: I understand this may be an academic / learning exercise for the mouse events or hostlisteners in angular, but the way I'd usually handle this is with the css :hover selector which is much simpler and performs better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, just replace **onmouseenter** with **mouseenter**

```
@HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter(){
          this.element.nativeElement.style.color = 'blue';
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try below :**

The name of the listening event is **mouseenter**, not **onmouseenter**. Hopefully you got it.:)

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

         @Directive({
          selector: '[setmycolor]'
           })
          export class SetmycolorDirective {

          constructor(private element:ElementRef) {
          element.nativeElement.style.color = 'red';
          }


          @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter(){ //SEE HERE
          this.element.nativeElement.style.color = 'blue';
          }

          }
```