# Update boolean value on mouseover/mouseout

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to update boolean value when mouseover/mouseout (it should change dynamically), to use it later with if else statement and assign some functions based on true/false. But it shows only `false` and never `true`. Can someone help me out?

ts:

```ts
    mouseEv: boolean;

    mouseOut(e) {
        this.mouseEv = false;
    }

    mouseOver(e) {
        this.mouseEv = true;
    } 

    ngOnInit(): void { 
        if(this.mouseEv == false){ func(); }
        else if(this.mouseEv == true) { otherFunc();};
    }
```

html:

```html
<div (mouseover)=" mouseOver($event)" (mouseout)="mouseOut($event)"></div>
```

EDIT:
I need to change boolean value dynamically, because I will use it with object that has functions in it and I can't call them from another function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use mouseover and mouseout in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491341/10115037)

Comment: You are checking `mouseEv` value on `ngOnInit` only which will executed only once.

Comment: @Karan how can I change it so it will be executed multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Create a function for example MouseHandlerEv in wich you recive the boolean value:

**.HTML file**

```
<div (mouseover)="mouseEvHandler(true)" (mouseout)="mouseEvHandler(false)"></div>
```

**.TS file**

```
mouseEvHandler(status){
   status ? FunctionTrue() : FunctionFalse();
}
```

Example:

```js
function mouseEvHandler(status){
   status ? sayHi() : sayBye();
}

function sayHi() {
  console.log('HI');
}

function sayBye() {
  console.log('Bye');
}
```

```html
 <div onmouseover="mouseEvHandler(true)" onmouseout="mouseEvHandler(false)">MESSAGE ON CONSOLE</div>
```

Extrapolate it to angular

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use it like below without creating a function for event:

```
<div (mouseover)="mouseEv=true" (mouseout)="mouseEv=false"></div>
```

You can also try passing true and false directly as method argument in mouseOver(true) and receive its value in component.

Comment: it does not change the value at all

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the values are checked only once at beginning of the component since you're checking the values in `ngOnInit()` hook. You could instead try to make it reactive using RxJS `fromEvent` and use it to trigger events.

Try the following

Template

```html
<div #mouseControl></div>
```

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('mouseControl') mouseControl: ElementRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.mouseControl.nativeElement, 'mouseover').subscribe(
      _ => otherFunc();
    );

    fromEvent(this.mouseControl.nativeElement, 'mouseout').subscribe(
      _ => func();
    );
  }
}
```