# Calling Angular function from HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, animation

I've created the following animation

[image]

CSS code

```
 .circles {
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  .circle-wrap {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .circle {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    visibility: hidden;
    animation: slideInFromRight 10.5s forwards linear infinite;
    @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
      animation: slideInFromRightSingle 18s forwards linear infinite;
    }
    &.left {
      box-shadow: -20px 20px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
      background-image: linear-gradient(51deg, #983781, #ff3f9a);
      margin-top: 0;
      animation-delay: 0s;
      @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
    }
    &.middle {
      box-shadow: -20px 20px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
      background-image: linear-gradient(33deg, #112d60, #983781);
      margin-top: -90%;
      animation-delay: 1.5s;
      @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
        margin-top: -100%;
        animation-delay: 3s;
      }
    }
    &.right {
      box-shadow: -20px 20px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeb857, #da3c91);
      margin-top: 30%;
      animation-delay: 3s;
      @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
        margin-top: -100%;
        animation-delay: 6s;
      }
    }    
  }
```

HTML code

```
<div class="quotes-section">
  <div class="row circles content">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 circle-wrap">
      <div class="circle left" animateOnScroll animationName="animated slideInFromRight" offset="120">
        <div class="text col-12" id="leftCircleText">
          1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 circle-wrap">
      <div class="circle middle" animateOnScroll animationName="animated slideInFromRight" offset="120" id="middleCircleText">
        2
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 circle-wrap">
      <div class="circle right" animateOnScroll animationName="animated slideInFromRight" offset="120" id="rightCircleText">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to fire an Angular function each time the circle enters from the right.
Since the user is nor clicking anything I cannot use `onClick= foo()`

**Is there another event that can work? or any other workaround to achieve this?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491225/how-to-use-mouseover-and-mouseout-in-angular-6/51491341

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev in what you sent the user still interacts with the object by mouse hovering over it. I'm looking for a solution with 0 interaction from the user it fires automatically when the object is entering or exiting the "screen"

Comment: Ohh I see. You would need to setInterval() poll the location of the divs, in order to see when it enters on screen. Some arithmetic needed.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev if there is no other event I can use then yes I'll have to use the setInterval, I was hoping there is an elegant way to achieve this :)

Comment: Technically, you could consider `requestAnimationFrame` is an "event" for things happening. There is also The `animationend` event.